# Date format return wrong date

Tags: java, date, datetime, date-conversion, java.util.date

I'm trying to format a Date object and convert that formatted one back to Date type object
This is my code

```
SimpleDateFormat inputDf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
System.out.println("before format  "+invoiceDate);
invoiceDate=inputDf.parse(inputDf.format(invoiceDate));
System.out.println("after format "+inputDf.format(invoiceDate));
System.out.println("after parse "+invoiceDate);
```

Out put from above code is

```
before format : Mon Jan 14 10:55:40 IST 2013
after format  : Mon Jan 14 2013 10:55:40 IST
after parse   : Mon Jan 14 10:55:40 IST 2013
```

You can see here after i parse the date object it converting back to original format(format which shows before format) but i want Date object like it appear in second print line(after format) thing is .format method returns String not a Date object, how can i fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is because the `SimpleDateFomat` does not impose itself upon the date. The `SimpleDateFormat` is merely a pattern to get a formated output out of any `Date`, but it does not change the date itself. `Date` does not have a format, so

```
System.out.println("before format  "+invoiceDate);
```

defaults to the default pattern format.

Actually, the `SimpleDateFormat` is exactly the way to achieve what you want, ie use it to properly format your output everytime you need it. Formating a date object gives you a representation of it, a `String`.

Comment: I can understand what you are telling ,then how can i change the format of the given date without convert it to String ? i want to change the format for use it in db query

Comment: @user1573690 : you can use any format in db query, do you want to insert record, if that is so, format of date doesn't matter

Comment: Haven't worked with MongoDB, but still, the format should be irrelevant, because date formats are output representations, not different versions of date objects. A date object has no specific format.

Answer (score 6):

The `Date` object doesn't define any format. `Date` is just a long number with time in it.
In order to modify its format you have to use a `String` object, as you did in your example.

If you analyze your example:

- before format: Shows the DEFAULT format for a `Date` that `System.out.println` offers.
- after format: Shows the format given after using the `SimpleDateFormat`.
- after parse: We are again in the first case.

Comment: I want final output as Date object(not as a String) with my format ("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz") how can i do that in such a case ?

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("after parse "+invoiceDate);
```

Here you just trying to print the `Date` object . The `Date` object , per se, doesn't have any format. *The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.* Hence we use `DateFormat` to format the output string which is printed on printing the `Date` object . To display the same output as second statement , you need to format it again.

```
System.out.println("after parse"+inputDf.format(invoiceDate));
```

Look at the Javadoc for implementation of the [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) for `Date` :

> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>
> **dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy**